# login_required decorator and urlresolver.reverse() in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have several views with `@login_required` decorator. And I'm going to use django.core.urlresolvers.reverse() function for redirection to them.

I wrote in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = ('myapp.views',
    '^(?P<key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/some-operation/$', 'some_operation'),
)
```

and in views.py:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(
     reverse('myapp.views.some_operation', kwargs={'key': item.key})
)
```

such that `some_operation` view function has `@login_required` decorator.

Django shows the following error:

```
Reverse for '<django.contrib.auth.decorators._CheckLogin object at 0x866782c>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'key': u'ab9d7x'}' not found.
```

It seems that Django is trying to find reverse match for login_required decorator function. How do I get avoided from this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found another way to do this from [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2). Use "named url" like this:

```
urlpatterns = ('myapp.views',
    url('^(?P<key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/some-operation/$', 'some_operation', name='myapp-some-operation'),
)
```

and

```
reverse('myapp-some-operation', kwargs={'key': item.key})
```

Comment: How can you pass additional kwargs in @login_required decorator? I can't do it

Comment: what version of Django were you using? Can that be achieved using the url templatetag?